# Python exchangelib Invalid credentials

Tags: python-3.x, office365, exchangelib

I have a python script that pulls attachments from Office 365 mailbox using exchangelib.
It was working fine up until couple of days ago when I started to get an error:

> Invalid credentials for https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

I suspect this is a due to a updates that Microsoft did for Office 365. The credentials are correct and account has EWS enabled.
I will appreciate any suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Office365 finally switched off Basic Authentication. In that case, you need to use OAuth instead. See https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#oauth-on-office-365 for a guide on doing that.

Comment: Thanks. I found your manual very helpful. I don't get a credential error anymore, but get this now "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to login microsoft account that provided on code using browser. Then it logged in. After that I closed. Then again checked python code for accessing mailbox using exchangelib. It worked. I think it taking any session or something. Before that it gives error like exchangelib.errors.UnauthorizedError: Invalid credentials for https://outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35510628)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).